# EventBus posts to unregistered subscriber

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus

While using EventBus, I have faced an unexpected situation that a subscription method of a Fragment is called one time even after the Fragment is unregistered.

Scenario is like this. I have an Activity containing a layout which any Fragment can be put. The Activity starts with a certain Fragment.

The Activity and the Fragment register themselves on their `onResume()` and unregister on `onPause()`. They have their own handlers for each for an event of same type.

By a dispatched event, the Activity replaces the Fragment with another by some condition. Then, the Fragment's `onPause()` gets called during removal process and `EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this)` is also executed.

Here, then, I expect the Fragment's handler not to be called from now. BUT it is called one time right after the Fragment is unregistered.

It seems like that EventBus doesn't handle the case of any subscriber is unregistered while event posting process. Anyone knows about this issue?

---

*Edited for more details*

- Related methods in the Fragment

  ```
  @Override
  public void onResume() {
      Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onResume()");
      super.onResume();
      EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
      Communicator.registerListener(listener);
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
      Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onPause()");
      Communicator.unregisterListener(listener);
      EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
      super.onPause();
  }

  @Subscribe(sticky = true)
  public void handleEvent(DeviceConnectionSelectEvent event) {
      if (event.container != null) {
          setDevice(event.container.getRapaelDevice());
      }
  }
  ```
- Call stack of `onPause()`

  ```
  Fragment.onPause()
            at com.neofect.rapael.client.bridge.app.device.kids.SmartKidsSensorDataFragment.onPause(SmartKidsSensorDataFragment.java:105)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performPause(Fragment.java:2139)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1117)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1234)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchPause(FragmentManager.java:2060)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performPause(Fragment.java:2135)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1117)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeFragment(FragmentManager.java:1349)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:695)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
            at com.neofect.rapael.client.bridge.app.MainActivity.changeDeviceDetailFragment(MainActivity.java:111)
            at com.neofect.rapael.client.bridge.app.MainActivity.handleEvent(MainActivity.java:100)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.invokeSubscriber(EventBus.java:485)
            at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postToSubscription(EventBus.java:416)
            at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postSingleEventForEventType(EventBus.java:397)
            at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postSingleEvent(EventBus.java:370)
            at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:251)
            at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postSticky(EventBus.java:292)
            at com.neofect.rapael.client.bridge.app.ui.device_connection_list.DeviceConnectionListPresenter.selectConnectionItem(DeviceConnectionListPresenter.java:114)
            at com.neofect.rapael.client.bridge.app.ui.device_connection_list.DeviceConnectionListPresenter.access$400(DeviceConnectionListPresenter.java:28)
            at com.neofect.rapael.client.bridge.app.ui.device_connection_list.DeviceConnectionListPresenter$1.onDeviceReady(DeviceConnectionListPresenter.java:179)
            at com.neofect.rapael.client.bridge.app.ui.device_connection_list.DeviceConnectionListPresenter$1.onDeviceReady(DeviceConnectionListPresenter.java:122)
            at com.neofect.communicator.CommunicationHandler$5.run(CommunicationHandler.java:90)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  ```
- Call stack of `handleEvent()` - This is called right after above `onPause()`

  ```
      Fragment.handleEvent()
            at com.neofect.rapael.client.bridge.app.device.kids.SmartKidsSensorDataFragment.handleEvent(SmartKidsSensorDataFragment.java:121)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.invokeSubscriber(EventBus.java:485)
            at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postToSubscription(EventBus.java:416)
            at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postSingleEventForEventType(EventBus.java:397)
            at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postSingleEvent(EventBus.java:370)
            at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:251)
            at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postSticky(EventBus.java:292)
            at com.neofect.rapael.client.bridge.app.ui.device_connection_list.DeviceConnectionListPresenter.selectConnectionItem(DeviceConnectionListPresenter.java:114)
            at com.neofect.rapael.client.bridge.app.ui.device_connection_list.DeviceConnectionListPresenter.access$400(DeviceConnectionListPresenter.java:28)
            at com.neofect.rapael.client.bridge.app.ui.device_connection_list.DeviceConnectionListPresenter$1.onDeviceReady(DeviceConnectionListPresenter.java:179)
            at com.neofect.rapael.client.bridge.app.ui.device_connection_list.DeviceConnectionListPresenter$1.onDeviceReady(DeviceConnectionListPresenter.java:122)
            at com.neofect.communicator.CommunicationHandler$5.run(CommunicationHandler.java:90)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  ```

The `handleEvent()` is called on the same call stack as `onPause()` according to the above. They are called in one event posting.

I'm guessing that the event dispatching loop (message queue loop) keeps the subscription list BEFORE starting posting, so it cannot handle the subscription removal done during posting process.

Comment: Just a naive guess: do you call `unregister()` before or after `super.onPause()`?

Comment: Can you post the call stack of your onPause where you unregister?

Comment: I've edited for more details.

Comment: You need to clarify your question to indicate in what thread (A) your Activity replaces your Fragment, (B) your Fragment unregisters and (C) the event that is dispatched to your event handler. From some of the stack trace above it is clear that you are invoking your event handlers in the thread of the caller. That can cause out of order message delivery, and IMHO should be always avoided as it means you are coupling your event creation with event consumption which is exactly what an EventBus was designed to avoid.

Comment: @William You got the wrong point. No event handler is being called by application, the event handler is called by EventBus implicitly. And the decoupling of event creation and consumption you mentioned is what I look for from using EventBus. I don't want to care when and where any other subscribers are called back, register and unregister with a certain event.

Comment: In this case, seemingly the subscriber needs to check whether it is called in the stack of event post process or not. Because if a subscriber unregisters itself in any event post process, it is not assured that its unregistration is processed.

Comment: @neo.kim you haven't understood my point. The default handling mechanism for EventBus is to deliver the event in the Thread of the poster.

Comment: @William Yeah, you right. But this is not the case. All the event handlers and posters in here are supposed to work on the UI thread. Even that doesn't mean they may be affected by each other. The point is a subscriber's process should not be interfered by any other subscribers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You're right.**

If you look into the source code of Event Bus, you will see that for **the same threads** (MAIN in your case) Event Bus doesn't recheck if a subscription is active during posting process:

### post()

Inside this method, Event Bus reaches `postSingleEventForEventType()` where it gets all subscriptions available at the moment and notifies them. Those that are from the same thread, are executed with no check:

```
EventBus#invokeSubscriber(subscription, event)
```

the others are scheduled and will be executed with a method that does checks:

```
EventBus#invokeSubscriber(pendingPost)
```

### unregister()

Inside this method, Event Bus reaches `unsubscribeByEventType()` where it gets the same subscriptions, deletes and deactivates the corresponding one:

```
List<Subscription> subscriptions = subscriptionsByEventType.get(eventClass);
for (...) {
    // ...
    subscription.active = false;
    subscriptions.remove(i);
}
```